# CSS menu overlay other content on open

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

**SOLUTION**

See snippet on working example!

---

**Question**

I really can't say what I am missing here. I simply cannot make the menu dropdown lay on top of the content below. In snippet below it is just text but it could be anything.

I have tried to apply `z-index` and `position: absolute;` whithout success.

I want to achieve what can be seen in below image just with a vertical menu. It overlays everything. Or is overlay a wrong word for this?

[image]

```js
$(function(){
$('#menuanimation').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('anime-menu').toggleClass('change');
});
});
```

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 color: #2F1919;
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border: 5px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;
 align-content: flex-start;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container p {
 font-size: 4vw;
 margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align:left;
 color: #2F1919;
 white-space: nowrap;
 white-space: pre-wrap;   /* CSS3 */  
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */  
 white-space: -pre-wrap;   /* Opera <7 */  
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;  /* Opera 7 */  
 word-wrap: break-word;   /* IE */
}

/*===== MENU below ======*/

.menu-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.menu-checkbox ~ .menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu-checkbox:checked ~ .menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu-checkbox:checked ~ .menu ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  border: 0px solid #2E181A;
 margin: 39px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: verdana, geneva, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #E6D9BD;
  /* #2E181A */
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
 z-index: 100;
  /* #E6D9BD */
}

.menu ul {
  background: #E6D9BD;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
 border: 5px solid #2E181A;
 border-top: none;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  opacity:0.95;
 filter:alpha(opacity=95);/* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.menu li {
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; /* */
}

.menu li a {
  color: #2E181A;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li ul {
 border: 0;
}

.menu li ul ul {
  display: none;
 
}

.menu li ul li {
  display: none;
}

.anime-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.anime-bar1, .anime-bar2, .anime-bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #2E181A;
 border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.change .anime-bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .anime-bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .anime-bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="menu-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="menu-checkbox" />
<label for="menu-checkbox"><div class="anime-menu" id="menuanimation">
  <div class="anime-bar1"></div>
  <div class="anime-bar2"></div>
  <div class="anime-bar3"></div>
</div></label>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="active">
    <li><a href="#">Frontpage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    I modsætning til hvad mange tror, er Lorem Ipsum ikke bare tilfældig tekst. Det stammer fra et stykke litteratur på latin fra år 45 f.kr., hvilket gør teksten over 2000 år gammel. Richard McClintock, professor i latin fra Hampden-Sydney universitet i
    Virginia, undersøgte et af de mindst kendte ord "consectetur" fra en del af Lorem Ipsum, og fandt frem til dets oprindelse ved at studere brugen gennem klassisk litteratur. Lorem Ipsum stammer fra afsnittene 1.10.32 og 1.10.33 fra "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (Det gode og ondes ekstremer), som er skrevet af Cicero i år 45 f.kr. Bogen, som var meget populær i renæssancen, er en afhandling om etik. Den første linie af Lorem Ipsum "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." kommer fra en linje i afsnit 1.10.32.
    Standardafsnittet af Lorem Ipsum, som er brugt siden 1500-tallet, er gengivet nedenfor for de, der er interesserede. Afsnittene 1.10.32 og 1.10.33 fra "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" af Cicero er også gengivet i deres nøjagtige udgave i selskab med
    den engelske udgave fra oversættelsen af H. Rackham fra 1914. Standardafsnittet af Lorem Ipsum, som er brugt siden 1500-tallet, er gengivet nedenfor for de, der er interesserede. Afsnittene 1.10.32 og 1.10.33 fra "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" af
    Cicero er også gengivet i deres nøjagtige udgave i selskab med den engelske udgave fra oversættelsen af H. Rackham fra 1914.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have  sub-categories? Do you want to get rid of the burger menu in favour of a horizontal menu and have menus dropping from each of those options? Your question is confusing

Comment: Actually I am trying to convert a horizontal menu into a burger menu. I don't want submenus as there are quite a few of them and that wont work on a mobile device. These are easy to hide though as I try to make the "new" dropdown menu work it just push the content beneath instead of "lay over" the content beneath.

Comment: well then, you can either a) use my answer and style the menu options so they align to the left, or widen them , or b) display the menu options inline instead of block ? I'm on my holidays, don't want to spend more time on this. Good luck,,

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks I will try and play around with this. Have a nice holiday :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the dropdown to display above the text? If so, maybe this is what you want.. I added padding at the top and an id to the div, transferring the inline `div` style into the css. You could add a class or an id to your `p` if you wanted the text to be different colours in each paragraph (and move color attribute out of the content div). Advisable to avoid inline style..

Hope this helps!

```js
$('#menuanimation').click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('anime-menu').toggleClass('change');
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #2E181A;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #2F1919;
}

.menu-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.menu-checkbox~.animemenu:before {
  content: "";
}

.menu-checkbox~.menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu-checkbox:checked~.menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 0px solid #2E181A;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: verdana, geneva, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2E181A;
  /* #2E181A */
  width: 100%;
  background: #2E181A;
  /* #E6D9BD */
}

.menu ul {
  background: #E6D9BD;
  display: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.menu li ul li {
  display: none;
}


/* Change the link color on hover */

.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.anime-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.anime-bar1,
.anime-bar2,
.anime-bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #E6D9BD;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.change .anime-bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .anime-bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .anime-bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}




#content p {
  padding-top: 65px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}

#content p::after {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  /*background-color: #FFF;*/
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="menu-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="menu-checkbox" />
<label for="menu-checkbox"><div class="anime-menu" id="menuanimation">
  <div class="anime-bar1"></div>
  <div class="anime-bar2"></div>
  <div class="anime-bar3"></div>
</div></label>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="active">
    <li><a href="#">Frontpage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p style="color: blue">
    I modsætning til hvad mange tror, er Lorem Ipsum ikke bare tilfældig tekst. Det stammer fra et stykke litteratur på latin fra år 45 f.kr., hvilket gør teksten over 2000 år gammel. Richard McClintock, professor i latin fra Hampden-Sydney universitet i
    Virginia, undersøgte et af de mindst kendte ord "consectetur" fra en del af Lorem Ipsum, og fandt frem til dets oprindelse ved at studere brugen gennem klassisk litteratur. Lorem Ipsum stammer fra afsnittene 1.10.32 og 1.10.33 fra "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (Det gode og ondes ekstremer), som er skrevet af Cicero i år 45 f.kr. Bogen, som var meget populær i renæssancen, er en afhandling om etik. Den første linie af Lorem Ipsum "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." kommer fra en linje i afsnit 1.10.32.
    Standardafsnittet af Lorem Ipsum, som er brugt siden 1500-tallet, er gengivet nedenfor for de, der er interesserede. Afsnittene 1.10.32 og 1.10.33 fra "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" af Cicero er også gengivet i deres nøjagtige udgave i selskab med
    den engelske udgave fra oversættelsen af H. Rackham fra 1914. Standardafsnittet af Lorem Ipsum, som er brugt siden 1500-tallet, er gengivet nedenfor for de, der er interesserede. Afsnittene 1.10.32 og 1.10.33 fra "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" af
    Cicero er også gengivet i deres nøjagtige udgave i selskab med den engelske udgave fra oversættelsen af H. Rackham fra 1914.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This just seem to push the below content. Please see image in updated question.

Comment: p.s. look at this http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/knuxedv9/ I'm sure you'll find other examples of burger-like menus online

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I did some reading on this stuff and solved it thanks to you.

Comment: @SimonJensen happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The div with text must have the `position: relative;` (means attach to) and .menu `{ position: absolute; }` (means what to attach)

```js
$('#menuanimation').click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('anime-menu').toggleClass('change');
});
```

```css
.menu-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.menu-checkbox~.animemenu:before {
  content: "";
}

.menu-checkbox~.menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu-checkbox:checked~.menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 0px solid #2E181A;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: verdana, geneva, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2E181A;
  /* #2E181A */
  width: 100%;
  background: #2E181A;
  /* #E6D9BD */
}

.menu ul {
  background: #E6D9BD;
  display: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.menu li ul li {
  display: none;
}


/* Change the link color on hover */

.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.anime-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.anime-bar1,
.anime-bar2,
.anime-bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #E6D9BD;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.change .anime-bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .anime-bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .anime-bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

div .myText {
    position: relative;
}
body {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #2E181A;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #2F1919;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="menu-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="menu-checkbox" />
<label for="menu-checkbox"><div class="anime-menu" id="menuanimation">
  <div class="anime-bar1"></div>
  <div class="anime-bar2"></div>
  <div class="anime-bar3"></div>
</div></label>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="active">
    <li><a href="#">Frontpage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="myText" style="display: block; background: #FFF;">
  <p style="color: blue">
    I modsætning til hvad mange tror, er Lorem Ipsum ikke bare tilfældig tekst. Det stammer fra et stykke litteratur på latin fra år 45 f.kr., hvilket gør teksten over 2000 år gammel. Richard McClintock, professor i latin fra Hampden-Sydney universitet i
    Virginia, undersøgte et af de mindst kendte ord "consectetur" fra en del af Lorem Ipsum, og fandt frem til dets oprindelse ved at studere brugen gennem klassisk litteratur. Lorem Ipsum stammer fra afsnittene 1.10.32 og 1.10.33 fra "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (Det gode og ondes ekstremer), som er skrevet af Cicero i år 45 f.kr. Bogen, som var meget populær i renæssancen, er en afhandling om etik. Den første linie af Lorem Ipsum "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." kommer fra en linje i afsnit 1.10.32.
    Standardafsnittet af Lorem Ipsum, som er brugt siden 1500-tallet, er gengivet nedenfor for de, der er interesserede. Afsnittene 1.10.32 og 1.10.33 fra "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" af Cicero er også gengivet i deres nøjagtige udgave i selskab med
    den engelske udgave fra oversættelsen af H. Rackham fra 1914. Standardafsnittet af Lorem Ipsum, som er brugt siden 1500-tallet, er gengivet nedenfor for de, der er interesserede. Afsnittene 1.10.32 og 1.10.33 fra "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" af
    Cicero er også gengivet i deres nøjagtige udgave i selskab med den engelske udgave fra oversættelsen af H. Rackham fra 1914.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but something seems to not work correctly in your snippet. Changing `.menu` to `position: absolute;` definetly change something.